# Перемещение рамки в инвентаре Unity2D

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть инвентарь и там есть рамка. Передвижение её осуществляеться в простом 
массиве

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) 
        {
            if(indexSlotForFrame - 1 >= 0)
            {
                indexSlotForFrame -= 1;
                leftRight--;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) 
        {
            if(indexSlotForFrame + 1 <= slots.Count - 1)
            {
                indexSlotForFrame += 1;
                leftRight++;
            }
        }   
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) 
        {
            if(indexSlotForFrame - frameAcross >= 0)
            {
                indexSlotForFrame -= frameAcross;
            }
        }   
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) 
        {
            if(indexSlotForFrame + frameAcross <= slots.Count - 1)
            {
                indexSlotForFrame += frameAcross;
            }
        }
```

и я просто запоминаю цифру и уже переношу туда слот

```
frame.transform.parent = slots[indexSlotForFrame].transform;
        frame.transform.position = slots[indexSlotForFrame].transform.position;
```

Но эта система не удобная, как видно по коду, потому что если я хочу открыть сундук, где есть еще один массив, то не могу их соединить же.
Вот может кто то скинуть мне видео или сам написать, как грамотно сделать систему перетаскивание рамки? (инвентарь для игры, которая будет на приставке)
Для того, что бы было понятно, как я хочу сделать, вот пример:

[image: пример]

Answer (score -3):

А что мешает вам вам "объединить" массивы?
Сделайте лист массивов и запоминайте текущий массив.
В итоге, когда вы осуществляете "перебор" элементов, просто проверяйте не выйдете ли вы за границу. Если новый индекс -1 - переключайте курсор на последний элемент предыдущего массива (получив сначала массив, а потом его длинну), если индекс равен длине текущего массива, пытайтесь переключиться на следующий массив.

Другими словами концепция именно перемещения примерно такая:

```
class Class1
{
    List<Slot[,]> _menus;

    int _xIndex;

    int _yIndex;

    int _maxX;

    int _maxY;

    Slot[,] _curentMenu;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            _xIndex--;
            if (_xIndex < 0)
            {
                ChangeMenu(Direction.Previous);
            }              
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            _xIndex++;
            if (_xIndex > _maxX)
            {
                ChangeMenu(Direction.Next);
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            _yIndex = Mathf.Clamp(++_yIndex, 0, _maxY);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            _yIndex = Mathf.Clamp(--_yIndex, 0, _maxY);
        }

        MoveFrame();
    }

    void ChangeMenu(Direction direction)
    {
        var index = GetNewIndex(direction);
        _curentMenu = _menus[index]; //Меняем текущий массив слотов
        _maxX = _curentMenu.GetUpperBound(0); //Получаем количество слотов по X
        _maxY = _curentMenu.GetUpperBound(1); //Получаем количество слотов по Y

        _yIndex = _yIndex > _maxY ? _maxY : _yIndex; //Если текущий слот по Y превышает высоту нового меню, устанавливаем высоту на последний слот по высоте
        _xIndex = direction == Direction.Next ? 0 : _maxX - 1; //Если перемещались в следующий - устанавливаем слот в ноль, если в предыдущий в послдний слот по X            
    }

    int GetNewIndex(Direction direction)
    {
        var curentIndex = _menus.IndexOf(_curentMenu); //Ищем индекс текущего меню в списка, чтобы понять, к кому мы можем перейти
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Next:
                curentIndex++;
                curentIndex = curentIndex == _menus.Count ? 0 : curentIndex;
                break;

            case Direction.Previous:
                curentIndex--;
                curentIndex = curentIndex < 0 ? _menus.Count - 1 : curentIndex;
                break;
        }

        return curentIndex;
    }

    void MoveFrame()
    {
        var slot = _curentMenu[_xIndex, _yIndex];
        //Перемещаем рамку в позицию текущего слота
    }

enum Direction
{
    Next,
    Previous
}
```

Comment: Интересно посмотреть, как вы реализуете перемещение курсора вверх и вниз, храня элементы в одномерном списке без кучи лишних проверок и условий :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, так ТС показал свой код) он не просил показать как сделать для перемещения вверх-вниз, у него только влево-вправо

Comment: 4 клавиши и гифка как бы намекают :)

Comment: Уже получше, но можно куда проще проверять выход за границы да и к тому же сделать более "удобный функционал" - берите модуль от числа